# knockout kendo numerictextbox events

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, kendo-ui

My project is MVC 5; I am trying to update a computed text when I spin kendo number text box.

```
<input class="numeric" data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox:price, events: { spin: change }" />
<hr />
Price: <strong data-bind="text: price"> </strong>
Items: <strong data-bind="text: price"> </strong>
Total: <strong data-bind="text: Total"> </strong>


var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.price = ko.observable(1);
        this.items = ko.observable(2);

        this.change = function() {
            alert("t");
        }
        self.Total = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.items() * parseInt("0" + self.price(), 10);
        });
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The events do not work, when I click outside the box, the computed value works.  Is this is the right way for events?

Comment: I'm not familiar with kendoUI but event binding syntax should be `event` not `events`. Not sure if that's the cure though.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html

`<input class="numeric" data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox:price, event: { spin: change }" />`

Comment: well it must be `event` no `'s` and `{ spin: change }` wrong one , it should be `{  change:spin }` . spin is some function in you viewModel .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to specify your binding like:

`data-bind="kendoNumericTextBox: { value: price, spin: updateOnSpin }"`

In the handler, you could either update the observable directly or trigger the widget's change event:

```
   this.updateOnSpin = function(e) {
      e.sender.trigger("change");   
   }
```

Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/yh6vokqd/